# Passing a Variable to IPV4Network or ip_network

Tags: python, ip, python-ipaddress

Can someone advise how i can pass a variable from a test file to the ipaddress module, i've tried a couple of different variations:

```
with open('VLANs.txt', 'r') as vlan_file:
for line in vlan_file:
    data = line.split(sep='\t')
    ip_address = ip.IPv4Network(data[4].strip())
    print(ip_address)

with open('VLANs.txt', 'r') as vlan_file:
for line in vlan_file:
    data = line.split(sep='\t')
    ip_address = ip.ip_network(data[4].strip())
    print(ip_address)
```

I get an address value error - i've tried casting to a string which is the usual type and to an IP address, none of which works.

Comment: can you show example from your file ('VLANs.txt')?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, here is 2x lines:
2172 DATA UAT VLAN 2172 UAT VLAN 2172 10.110.172.0/24
2173 DATA UAT VLAN 2173 UAT VLAN 2173 10.110.173.0/24

Comment: Check for tabs or spaces in original file. Probabaly `[4]` is not working, because there are no tabs in original file.